# Get product and category from magento by using REST

Tags: magento

I create application mobile with PhoneGap for shopping. I use Magento to add products and categories, the problem is how can get product and categories from Magento to my application mobile by using APi REST 
I use version 1.9 of Magento . 
please Help me and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See This link

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111338/how-to-retrieve-products-from-magento-rest-api

before that see official documentation of magento [REST api](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html)

Then to get final oauth token and oauth token secrete see this link

[How to use POSTMAN rest client with magento REST api with Oauth. How to get Token and Token Secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045800/how-to-use-postman-rest-client-with-magento-rest-api-with-oauth-how-to-get-toke)

Then fill the oauth token and secrete in the example from first link, you will get the list of products