# 403 Access Denied for customers in Magento REST API

Tags: api, rest, magento

I am getting 403 Access Denied error for http://www.example.com/rest/api/customers in Magento 1.9.2.4. Everything in admin side rest & admin roles and resources are proper and set to "All". Though http://www.example.com/rest/api/products is working but not able to fetch customers and getting Access Denied.

I tried with other Magento version setups also in same server but all gives 403 Access Denied error for customers and working fine for products.
Server is using SUPHP. What could be solution?

Thanks

Comment: if you are making call through browser then you are logged in as guest, so only product resources are available to guest.

Comment: I am logged in as Master Admin. And rest api roles have "All" privileges for customers, orders etc. Still gives Access Denied error. I cleared Magento cache/cookies several times.

Answer (score 0):

How are you making the calls? Is it a php script or are you using something like this? You need to give this detail to identify the erroe

[How to use POSTMAN rest client with magento REST api with Oauth. How to get Token and Token Secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045800/how-to-use-postman-rest-client-with-magento-rest-api-with-oauth-how-to-get-toke)

I have found this tutorial is great to pinpoint where the error are ie the parameters not being encoded with the url etc

Comment: I am trying using firefox RESTClient Api add-on. Also created separate file using http://inchoo.net/magento/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/ but it gives same error. Access denied for customers and orders but works for products. Not sure what is missing.