# rest-assured OAuth 1.0a How can I insert both Header and Query params in the request

Tags: rest, magento, oauth, rest-assured

Magento's 1.9 REST API needs both Authorization Header and oauth query params, but oauth() only allows for either OAuthSignature.HEADER, or QUERY_STRING

```
given().auth().oauth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, 
            SECRET_TOKEN,OAuthSignature.HEADER)
```

I tracked the code down to com.jayway.restassured.internal.httpAuthConfig.process(..), but I am not sure what to do from here.

Q: Is there a filter or some method that would allow me to force both?

TL;DR
I started by referring to this: [How to use POSTMAN rest client with magento REST api with Oauth. How to get Token and Token Secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045800/how-to-use-postman-rest-client-with-magento-rest-api-with-oauth-how-to-get-toke)
The last statement

> Note, you must check the "Add params to header" checkbox in order for Magento REST calls to work properly.

Using Postman, OAuth 1.0 GET works when I check the box and fails
when I don't, with 403 access denied. This is the same response I get when I use OAuthSignature.QUERY_STRING in rest-assured.

```
WORKS: Sent from Postman (add params to header)

GET /api/rest/products?oauth_consumer_key=<my-consumer-key>&oauth_token=<my-oauth-token>&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1471929347&oauth_nonce=LJ3o2K&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=0Any8rQ+XjbnWcdXmpHFujg1V7o= HTTP/1.1
Host: dockerized-magento.local
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="<my-consumer-key>",oauth_token="<my-oauth-token>",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1471996573",oauth_nonce="ElK9Fx",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="SvDfMxrWj1O0P2%2FWPOomEVEb93c%3D"
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
Postman-Token: 9348e805-3c6f-54d7-082f-a1458164725d
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

rest-assured OAuthSignature.QUERY_STRING

```
Doesn't Work: OAuthSignature.QUERY_STRING

GET /api/rest/products?oauth_nonce=-316324336&oauth_signature=TlANZu5ogxowYJCpr2V7W448tjw%3D&oauth_token=<my-oauth-token>&oauth_consumer_key=<my-consumer-key>&oauth_timestamp=1471996938&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 0
Host: dockerized-magento.local
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_77)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

RESP: {"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}]}}
```

Same failed response using Postman with out "add params to header")

```
Doesn'T WORK: Sent from Postman (NO - add params to header)

GET /api/rest/products?oauth_consumer_key=<my-consumer-key>&oauth_token=<my-oauth-token>&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1471976516&oauth_nonce=OTWTNW&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=Dsh5TEErEC9rMbKakta1v2E7ZTw= HTTP/1.1
Host: dockerized-magento.local
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36
Postman-Token: f9800e1c-b259-f025-cf48-68e483283869
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Response: {"messages":{"error":[{"code":403,"message":"Access denied"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake made, HEADER option works fine.
The Postman link above, which works fine and was a great help, led me to believe I needed both url params and headers. I went back to postman and deleted the url params after adding params to headers. This worked fine. 
I went back and found my consumer keys were wrong.

Tip: Magento Consumer Keys and Secret are not "copyable", use firebug!