# getting "oauth_problem=nonce_used" when trying to get token and token secret from magento through POSTMAN

Tags: rest, magento, postman

I'm a beginner with this while magento/postman thing. Right now I'm trying to get a token and token secret from magento using postman, but I've been stuck for days now and I don't know where else to look for solutions.

I'm using a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045800/how-to-use-postman-rest-client-with-magento-rest-api-with-oauth-how-to-get-toke/28072813#28072813?newreg=84c29159583c43a1bd4d6e9904936ef7) posted by Franklin Strube (user from this forum), but I can't get past the first step since the response I get is "oauth_problem=nonce_used".

I've already checked the following: 
- No special ports re being used to connect to my webpage
- REST roles, attributes and clients have been set up correctly in order to have access to the APIs.
- My user has already a key and a secretm which I'm using to send the request via Postman through the GET method.

This is how my postman looks right now: [image]

Please, I'd appreciate any help you can provide me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I came across same problem few days ago, If you failed after 2nd or 3rd step, you should again start with oauth/'initiate. you missed add params to header